# Returning a list of x and y coordinate tuples

Tags: python-3.x, tuples

I am trying to return a list of x and y co-ordinate tuples after reading a text file with numbers in it for example:

```
68,125
113,69
65,86
108,149
152,53
```

I have got to the point where i return a list of numbers but not as pairs in a tuple.

here is my code:

```
def read_numbers(filename):
    numbers = []
    input_file = open(filename, "r")
    content = input_file.readlines()
    numbers = [word.strip() for word in content]
    input_file.close()
    return numbers
def main():
    numbers = read_numbers('output.txt')
    print(numbers)

main()
```

Comment: Needs to look something like this: [(68, 125), (113, 69), (65, 86), (108, 149), (152, 53)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read each line, then split each line by comma and convert each piece of that split to an int using map. Finally convert it into tuple

```
coords = [tuple(map(int, line.split(","))) for line in lines]
```

This gives the output:

```
[(68, 125), (113, 69), (65, 86), (108, 149), (152, 53)]
```

Your full code might look something like this:

```
with open("output.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

coords = [tuple(map(int, line.split(","))) for line in lines]
print(coords)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a generator as it allows you to use additional control structure then list comprehension:

```
def parse_file(file):
    for line in file:
        num1, num2 = line.split(",") #this can't be done in list comprehension
        yield (int(num1), int(num2))
```

Then your `read_numbers` could look like this:

```
def read_numbers(filename):
    with open(filename,"r") as f:
        return list(parse_file(f))
```